# Economy vs Economics: Is it like medication vs medicine?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

What I understand is:

Medication is what medical doctors (or perhaps I should say physicians lol) prescribe while medicine is what physicians study.

I like to think medicine is the study of, well, medication.

Soooo similarly economics is the study of economy?

Other questions:

1. [Economy or Economics, this is the question!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192662/economy-or-economics-this-is-the-question) - I don't think this says economics is the study of economy.
2. [Economics SE or Economy SE?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/economics-se-or-economy-se) - is I think not not related to what I'm asking

Comment: It isn't as simple as that, because all these words have different shades of meaning. _Medicine_ can mean _medication_ as well as 'the study of the diagnosis and treatment of disease'. _Economics_ is the theoretical study of the _economies_ of countries, organisations etc.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "economics" is:

> the branch of knowledge concerned with the production, consumption, and transfer of wealth.

While for "economy" it is:

> the state of a country or region in terms of the production and consumption of goods and services and the supply of money.

"economics" is usually a term used for education, such as a major or subject in school, it means the learning process and knowledge of "production, consumption, and transfer of wealth.".

Example sentence with "economics":

> She majored in economics
>
> He gained a first class Honours degree in economics.
>
> He is regarded as a committed supporter of a radical free-market economics policy.

However, "economy" is different, it means the state of a country/city in terms of the supply of money. You usually use it with:

> The war altered the country's economy
>
> An increase in tourism will help the city's economy
>
> The economy was affected by the establishment of a land tax.